# change different words in text with python3

Tags: python-3.x

I want to change the  '.........' on this text from the list down but I'm not getting the output I'm looking for .

here's what i tried to do :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re 
reg = re.compile('\.{10}')


text = """
        
    
    it was a (1) .......... ,cold November day. 

    I woke up to the (2) .......... smell of (3) .......... 

    roasting in the (4) .......... downstairs. I (5) .......... 

    down the strais to see if i could help (6) ..........
 
    the dinner. My mome said , "See if (7)  .......... needs a fresh (8) .......... 
 
    " So i carried a trat of glasses full of (9) .......... into the (10) .......... room. 
 
    Whem i got tyhere, I could'nt believe (11) .......... ! 
 
    There were (12) .......... (13) .......... on the (14) .......... !

"""

replace = ['TEST0', 'TEST1', 'TEST2', 'TEST3', 'TEST4', 'TEST5', 'TEST6', 'TEST7', 'TEST8', 'TEST9', 'TEST10', 'TEST11', 'TEST12', 'TEST13']
mo = reg.findall(text)

for i in range(len(mo))  :
  print(text.replace(mo[i],replace[i]))
```

Comment: easier way would be to split the string with `.......` and the add elem from `replace` list and generate a  full string `text`.

Comment: that didnt work for me or i'am missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood, you need to replace those `..........` with elems from list `replace`. I used `string.split()` function to split the multiline text and added the string one by one with corresponding replacement.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

text = """
    it was a (1) .......... ,cold November day.

    I woke up to the (2) .......... smell of (3) ..........

    roasting in the (4) .......... downstairs. I (5) ..........

    down the strais to see if i could help (6) ..........

    the dinner. My mome said , "See if (7)  .......... needs a fresh (8) ..........

    " So i carried a trat of glasses full of (9) .......... into the (10) .......... room.

    Whem i got tyhere, I could'nt believe (11) .......... !

    There were (12) .......... (13) .......... on the (14) .......... !

"""

replace = ['TEST0', 'TEST1', 'TEST2', 'TEST3', 'TEST4', 'TEST5', 'TEST6', 'TEST7', 'TEST8', 'TEST9', 'TEST10', 'TEST11', 'TEST12', 'TEST13']

text = text.split("..........") # generates a list of text without dots
string = ""  # empty string that we populate with content now

for i in range(0, len(text)-1):
    string += text[i] + replace[i]  # adding replacement to text

print(string)
```

Comment: that worked  very well it exactly what i wanted

Answer (score 1):

This works, but it is a little cheeky. It relies on the fact that your original text can be turned it a format string relatively painlessly. Basic "older" string formatting allows us to do replacement like

```
print("The sky is %s" % "blue")
```

resulting in:

```
The sky is blue
```

we can extend this with multiple replacement placeholders and values (as a tuple). For example:

```
print("The sky is %s and the grass is %s" % ("blue", "green"))
```

resulting in:

```
The sky is blue and the grass is green
```

By extending this, we might think about as a fist step replacing all the `..........` with our placeholder `%s`. Then we could use the older style string formatting by using this updated input string and the array of replacements cast as a `tuple`.

```
text = """
    it was a (1) .......... ,cold November day.

    I woke up to the (2) .......... smell of (3) ..........

    roasting in the (4) .......... downstairs. I (5) ..........

    down the strais to see if i could help (6) ..........

    the dinner. My mome said , "See if (7)  .......... needs a fresh (8) ..........

    " So i carried a trat of glasses full of (9) .......... into the (10) .......... room.

    Whem i got tyhere, I could'nt believe (11) .......... !

    There were (12) .......... (13) .......... on the (14) .......... !

"""

replace = ['TEST0', 'TEST1', 'TEST2', 'TEST3', 'TEST4', 'TEST5', 'TEST6', 'TEST7', 'TEST8', 'TEST9', 'TEST10', 'TEST11', 'TEST12', 'TEST13']

print(text.replace("..........", "%s") % tuple(replace))
```

This prints out:

```
it was a (1) TEST0 ,cold November day.

I woke up to the (2) TEST1 smell of (3) TEST2

roasting in the (4) TEST3 downstairs. I (5) TEST4

down the strais to see if i could help (6) TEST5

the dinner. My mome said , "See if (7)  TEST6 needs a fresh (8) TEST7

" So i carried a trat of glasses full of (9) TEST8 into the (10) TEST9 room.

Whem i got tyhere, I could'nt believe (11) TEST10 !

There were (12) TEST11 (13) TEST12 on the (14) TEST13 !
```

I guess technically you could get the same result with "new" formatting as well via:

```
print(text.replace("..........", "{}").format(*replace))
```

Comment: i  dont under stand what happening here exactly could you explain a bit more ? im still fairly new

Comment: so we converted the list to a tuple to avoid creating a for loop and replacing every ".........." with every value of the tuple() ? or its a diffrent idea ?

Comment: @seprico I added some addition description with the intention of making the answer it clearer.

Comment: i understand it more better now thank you !